# Crystal Reports embedded in ASP .Net : Reliability

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Some years ago, I use Crystal Reports XI.5, I had problem when I generated long reports (> 25 pages) with the viewer embedded in a ASP .Net web page. If the report was short, there wasn't a problem.

My solution is to use Crystal 9 with the Java component using ASP 3 (!!!!) but there are security warning with the Java applet and it's time to upgrade it.

Does someone had the same problem with CR XI.5 ? Are the last version (CR 2011) reliable ?

(Note : I can't buy CR Web server)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've always taken when serving CR/XI reports via ASP.NET is to publish reports to a destination accessible by my .NET app and then read them from there.  Saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: did you use the asp .net crystal reports report viewer component ? I had really a lot a lot of problems with that component. but it is too far away ... i don't remember all the details. Did you try the new version of crystal reports ?

Comment: No. I try to maintain separation between CR/XI and ASP.NET whenever possible, so I don't use the component.

Comment: I don't unterstand what is your technic .. how do you transmit parameters ? what is the ui component ? thank you a lot

Comment: If you only have a few parameters with a few possible values, then you can have the reports pre-rendered and use a naming convention to fetch them.  But if you have a large number of varying parameters, then this method won't do the trick.